# Archimesh export as fbx leaves large box on windows and doors

Tags: export, add-on, .fbx, unreal-engine, archimesh-add-on

I am trying to export a mesh made with the Archimesh addon as an .fbx for use in Unreal engine. Whenever I export any room with a door or a window, the auto hole doesn't follow after export.

At first I figured it was just an issue with applying modifiers, so I dug through the outliner and applied all object modifiers that were available on my objects, but the large box surrounding windows and doors remains after export.

Is this possible to work through? I read somewhere online that people use archimesh to prototype levels in unity, so I imagine its possible to do the same with unreal engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box is used by the boolean modifier to cut the hole in the wall for the door/window. After you have applied the modifiers, you can delete the objects called "CTRL_hole" to keep them from being exported.